# Return Variable value in If Condition C#

Tags: c#

[image]

I Want use this variable value in if condition Like
if(20 > 13 && 20 < 18) .....

Comment: Please be clear about what you mean. Also, please include *code*, not a screenshot of your code.

Comment: it would be great if you paste your code here rather than showing its picture.

Comment: First and foremost 20 will never be less than 18... which value is your variable???

Comment: Is your string always going to be like "a > b && c < d" or it can be anything(including any condition)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways (many ways but i prefer these).

**Slow way:** (really slow) Use CodeDom to compile string at run time. sample:

```
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

//...

private static void Main()
{
    string Tempreture = "20 > 13 && 20 < 18";
    bool? result = Evaluate(Tempreture);
    if (!result.HasValue)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("invalid expression.");
    }
    else if (result.Value)
    {
        //...
    }
    else
    {
        //...
    }
}

public static bool Evaluate(string condition)
{
    // code to compile.
    const string conditionCode = "namespace Condition {{public class Program{{public static bool Main(){{ return {0};}}}}}}";

    // compile code.
    var cr = new CSharpCodeProvider().CompileAssemblyFromSource(
        new CompilerParameters { GenerateInMemory = true }, string.Format(conditionCode, condition));

     if (cr.Errors.HasErrors) return null;

    // get the method and invoke.
    var method = cr.CompiledAssembly.GetType("Condition.Program").GetMethod("Main");
    return (bool)method.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

**Fast way:** Use [Ncalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) library to dynamically parse expressions.

```
using NCalc;

// ...

string Tempreture = "20 > 13 && 20 < 18";
NCalc.Expression e = new Expression(Tempreture);
if (e.HasErrors())
{
    throw new ApplicationException("invalid expression");
}
if ((bool)e.Evaluate())
{
    //...
}
else
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Please Tell Me Another Way to do it

Comment: @ImranPathan can you tell me what is the problem with these two ways? if you are stucked at some somewhere tell me so i can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `x = 20`

Then you can do this:

```
if(x > 13 && x <18)
```

Comment: 20 > 13 && 20 < 18 This value comming from Database as it is i wnt to place it in if condition like  if(20 > 13 && 20 < 18)

Comment: oh ok. So you want to evaluate the expression. You can use CSharpCodeProvider, but you need to create a proper class and eval method inside it